# DataConversionWarning when trying to see the performance on a validation test

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Right now I am working on a text clasification task ( I want to see if a response is even human or bot generated). Unfortunately, when I try to see what is my accuracy on a validation dataset, I get this error :

> Blockquote DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
>     y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

I tried to use ravel() method and reshaping, but I still get the warning and I couldn't find something useful on the internet.

This is how a part of my code looks like:

```
with open('validation.txt') as f:
reader = DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    target_values_validation.append(int(row['human-generated']))
    row['response']=row['response'].replace('<first_speaker>', '')
    row['response'] = row['response'].replace('<second_speaker>', '')
    row['response'] = row['response'].replace('<third_speaker>', '')
    row['response'] = row['response'].replace('@@ ', '')
    row['response'] = row['response'].replace('<at>', '')
    row['response'] = row['response'].replace('<url>', '')
    row['response'] = row['response'].replace('<number>', '')
    list_response_validation.append(row['response'])
y_validation=numpy.asarray(target_values,dtype=int)
    text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                 ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                 ('clf', MultinomialNB())])
text_clf=text_clf.fit(list_response_train, y)
predicted1=text_clf.predict(list_response_validation)
accuracy=numpy.mean(predicted1==y_validation.ravel())
print(accuracy)
```

Every suggestion or alternative solution is highly aprecieted.

Comment: 1. fix indents  2. you create `y_validation` but then fit `y`, which do you want? 3. what is `y.shape` and `y.dtype`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, actually I totally forgot to apply ravel() to y as well. The indents are good in my text editor but I think I messed them up when I copy-pasted the code. y is my target value vector used to train the model and y_validation is used for testing the performance. My only issue now is that the accuracy is 0.0 and I don`t understand why.